# React Native: Prevent remote debugger from opening in Chrome

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, emulation

I've written a Bash script to open React Native Debugger (desktop app) before running my iOS emulator itself. By default my iOS emulator has "Remote JS Debugging" on, and when the emulator starts up, it opens the remote JS debugger in Chrome. So I end up with React Native Debugger and the Chrome remote JS debugger both open, and these conflict with each other and sometimes cause the app to crash.

My question is: is there a way to prevent the iOS emulator from automatically opening the remote JS debugger in Chrome?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a solution? I use Vscode and hate it when it launches Chrome whenever debugger isn't running.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the `REACT_DEBUGGER` env variable to some failing path, so it will fail behind the scenes when trying to open it.